# Loss of sound with HDMI television for screen

Tags: sound, hdmi

I'm using 14.04 with a Philips TV connected through HDMI as a screen with loudspeakers.

Most of the time, everything works fine, but occasionally, the sound just disappears, while everything appears fine. Everything "works" as far as the computer is aware.

Logging off and on fixes the issue.